# [Symfony][FOSUserBundle] Can I get a user's former password

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using the FOSUserBundle on a Symfony project, and I would like to know if, when a user changes his password, I can have access to his **former password**. The one he's supposed to enter in the "current password" field.

I have a system of encryption on my project, and it's partially based on the user's password, that's why I need it, to update the user's encryption settings.

I created a **listener** when the user changes his password but I don't know how to get his former password. Or current password, whatever.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **NO**. If user won't give you his current password by typing it in form it's impossible to *guess* his password.

Only option to have access to current user's password is when password is stored in database in plain text which is rather not the case. 
The way passwords are stored in db usually is by using [hashing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) which are designed to be impossible to invert - you are able to hash your password but you can't unhash it.

In theory you could try to use [Rainbow tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table) but it's not something you could use in regular way on every passwprd change because it's very CPU heavy.

Answer (score -2):

1. encrypt the new password.
2. compare the hash of the new password and the hash password in the database.

Comment: 1. When you say to "encrypt" the new password, do you mean to *hash* it? 2. Let's say you compare the new hash and the one in the DB. Then you know whether they are the same or not, but this is not what the question is asking.

Comment: If the hash is the same, then we can use the password from the form where necessary

Comment: you can't simply do that because the hashing function always gives diffirent results each time you do it even if given the same password